# How to correctly nest where clause in laravel?

Tags: php, laravel

I'm looking to nest a where query inside a where query.

i want it to allways check if type is %Accu%.

```
$products = Product::where('type','LIKE', '%Accu%')
            ->where('beschrijving', 'LIKE','%'. $searchquery .'%')
            ->where('artikelcode','LIKE','%' . $searchquery . '%')
            ->where('prijs','LIKE','%' . $searchquery . '%')
            ->get();
```

I tried:

```
$products = Product::where('type','LIKE', '%Accu%', function($query) use ($searchquery) {
            $query->where('beschrijving', 'LIKE','%'. $searchquery .'%')->orWhere('artikelcode','LIKE','%' . $searchquery . '%')->orWherewhere('prijs','LIKE','%' . $searchquery . '%')->get();
        })->get();
```

Any help is appreciated

Comment: what the error?

Comment: Return closure cant be converted to string

Comment: are you try remove get() from nested function?

Comment: I will try in 5 minutes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For nesting you need to pass `Closure` callback to the where condition function. You can achieve this using following

```
$products = Product::where('type','LIKE', '%Accu%')
    ->where(function($query) use ($searchquery) {
        $query->where('beschrijving', 'LIKE','%'. $searchquery .'%')
            ->orWhere('artikelcode','LIKE','%' . $searchquery . '%')
            ->orWherewhere('prijs','LIKE','%' . $searchquery . '%');
    })->get();
```